# Bind Windows Key in Enlightenment

Tags: enlightenment

so I set up Arch with Enlightenment. You open the "Run Everything" application using alt+esc by default. I'd like to use the Windows Key for that. The key bindings manager only allows for key pairs. Like modifier + key... so I can't do it in the key bindings manager. [At least, I think I can't].

So, how can I run "Run Everything" using the Windows Key only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design its not currently possible to bind to just a meta key such as Win, Ctrl or Alt. This is sone of few places where the enlightenment config takes the simpler approach over the more options approach.

Personally I find this ok, I have Win+R bound to "Run Everything" Win+T bound to launching a terminal and Win+F bound to launching the filemanager.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get around this though this method is kind of hacky and prevents a user from using the windows key as a modifier

1. Settings->Settings panel->input->keyboard
2. Under compose add a remap from Windows key to something else
3. Key Bindings->add->press windows key->assign action

Tested in enlightenment 22